# Is there any Laravel package for sending mail with office 365 mail?

Tags: laravel, email, office365

I ve been in a idea of moving to office 365.

I have to send emails to users using laravel app. The problem is, I could not be able to use SMTP for some reason.

So i planned to use a package just like `aws`. And fortunately i found one.

https://github.com/motze92/office365-mail

The problem with this package is, there is no error from the mailer, but instead, I have a problem in delivering the messages to the recipient.

So i searched for other packages, but i could not find any.

Please help me by suggesting me a package or fixing the issues with SMTP or this package.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why can't you use SMTP?  What errors do you get?

Answer (score 0):

there's no need to use package.. You just need to update your .env

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=OFFICE365_SMTP
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=YOUR_OFFICE_365_USERNAME
MAIL_PASSWORD=YOUR_OFFICE_365_PASSWORD
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I am able to find the issue.
By default, Modern Authentication is enabled as security defaults in Azure portal is turned `ON` for the organization if it has to use Azure portal.

So I had to turn off security defaults in Azure portal and then, SMTP works fine.

I dont need a package to send an email as SMTP works just fine.

For more info : Click [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/exchange-team-blog/basic-authentication-and-exchange-online-july-update/ba-p/1530163)